# Backbone.js vs Pusherapp - What is the difference?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, socket.io

What's the main difference between Backbone.js and a service like Pusher or socket.io?

When should I use one instead of the other?

thanks

Answer (score 4):

Backbone is MVC, socket.io is WebSockets. They are radically different

Comment: As @Rayno says, Backbone.js is an MVC JavaScript framework. [Pusher](http://pusher.com) is a realtime messaging infrastructure as a service and [socket.io](http://socket.io) is a WebSocket (with fallback) technology.

Backbone.js can use AJAX polling to check for updates whilst technologies like Pusher and socket.io could be used in combination with Backbone.js to push notifications about updates in collections/models from the server to the client as detailed in this [realtime Backbone.js article](http://blog.pusher.com/2011/6/21/backbone-js-now-realtime-with-pusher).